# loading images after page has been loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, signalr

I have a page that uses signalR. The server calls a client function and passes in image paths to it. ie 'Contents/myimage.png'. Inside the client function I use jquery to load these images. I'm not getting any errors in chrome and the images don't have that default didn't load picture in them but the images are also not there. The function is getting called. What am I missing?

```
client.onStart = function(myPortrait){
   $("#myPortrait").load(myPortrait);
}


<img id="myPortrait" width="256" height="256" />
```

Comment: When you get the myPortrait path, can you copy into a new window to open the image?  Looks like the path might not be complete (I'd expect):  'mysite/contents/myimage.png'.

Comment: any errors in the console?? make sure you check that first

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$.load` replaces the html with the content from the url, eg for a function that returns `<div>replacement</div>`, you would do:

```
$("#mydiv").load(url);
```

and you'd get

```
<div id='mydiv'><div>replacement</div></div>
```

in this case as data is returning the url to the image, you want to set the *src* of the image, not replace the html, so change to:

```
client.onStart = function(myPortrait) {
    $("#myPortrait").prop("src", myPortrait);
}
```

---

if you were doing this via an ajax call (rather than a SignalR call):

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
}).done(function(data) {
    $("#myPortait").prop("src", data);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead to use:

```
$("#myPortrait").load(myPortrait);
```

you may use:

```
$("#myPortrait").attr('src', myPortrait);
```